# Primes between consecutive cubes

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I am looking at Dudley's proof of the existence of Mill's constant. It starts out as follows

> The proof depends on the following theorem: there is an integer $A$ such that if $n>A$, then there is a prime $p$ such that
>   $$ n^3 < p < (n+1)^3 -1.$$
>   We will not prove this but we will use it to determine a sequence of primes$\ldots$

**Where can I find a proof of this theorem?**

Answer (score 8):

Ingham [1] proved that for all large enough $n$ there is a prime $p$ such that $n^3<p<(n+1)^3.$ That this holds for all $n>0$ is not currently known. Cheng claims a proof, but Dudek disputes this:

> We should note that a result has been given by Cheng [2], in which he purports to show the above theorem for the range $n\ge\exp(\exp(15))$. We should, however, note that he incorrectly goes from
>   $$
> n^3\ge\exp(\exp(45))
> $$
>   to
>   $$
> n\ge\exp(\exp(15))
> $$
>   in establishing his result. There are some other errors also, notably in his
>   proof of Theorem 3 in his paper [2], the first inequality sign is backwards and
>   he has used Chebyshev's $\psi$-function instead of the $\theta$-function.

The best result I know is in the same paper, proving that there is a prime between $n^3$ and $(n+1)^3$ for $n\ge\exp(\exp(33.217))$.

See also [A060199](https://oeis.org/A060199) in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/).

[1] A. E. Ingham, On the difference between consecutive primes, *Quarterly Journal of Mathematics* ***1*** (1937), pp. 255-266.

[2] Adrian Dudek, [An Explicit Result for Primes Between Cubes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4233)

Answer (score 4):

This paper written fairly recently, and some of its sources might be useful: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.2113v2.pdf

Comment: +1 Thank you! That is exceedingly strange that the above proof was published so recently. Dudley's proof which mentions the theorem was published in 1978.

Comment: @smokeweedeveryday It's effectively due to Ingham with a result from 1937. I can't find a freely available version of his paper, though, but you can find it [here](http://qjmath.oxfordjournals.org/content/os-8/1/255.full.pdf).

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion. See Mill's original article http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183510803

Comment: @Mike Shucks: http://qjmath.oxfordjournals.org/content/os-8/1/255.full.pdf+html?sid=232e936a-3292-4b7d-825e-f8898f11e8a4 I ain't got 38 bucks!

Comment: Yeah, I can't find a source for the original proof (and I don't even have access to that at an institution - seems only four institutions in the US do! How silly.)

Answer (score 2):

We know since Ingham that

$$
p_{n+1} - p_n < K p_n^{5/8},
$$
where $p_n$ is the $n^{\rm th}$ prime and $K$ is a positive integer constant. Now let $N>K^8$ be a positive integer and $p_n$ the greatest prime smaller than $N^3$. Then we have:

$$
\begin{align}
N^3 &< p_{n+1} \\
&< K p_n^{5/8} + p_n \\
&< N^3 + KN^{15/8} \\
&< N^3 + N^2 \ \ \ \text{(since $N>K^8$)} \\
&< N^3 +3N^2 +3N 
\end{align}
$$

And now using the last line of the above reasoning we find that

$$
N^3 < p_{n+1} < \left({N + 1}\right)^3 - 1.
$$