# On primes between consecutive $n-th$ powers.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The Opperman conjecture, is the statement that for every integer $x\geq 2$, there always exists a prime btween $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2$.

How about for every integer $n\geq 3$, is there always a prime between $x^n$ and $(x+1)^n$, $x\geq 2$ ?

Comment: Check this question from 2014: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717838/primes-between-consecutive-cubes

Comment: the question as I understand it is : is there a $n$ such that it is proven that there is always a prime between $x^n$ and $(x+1)^n$ ? in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture#Partial_results they say that for any $n > 1+21/40$ it is true when $x$ is large enough

Comment: @user1952009 Then it would be proven that there is always a prime between $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2$ for large $x$, because $n=2>1+21/40$. This is not the case.

Comment: you are right,  that there is a prime in $[x,x+C x^{21/40}]$ and because $(x+1)^a - x^a < C' x^{a-1}$ we get that there is a prime in $[x^a,(x+1)^a]$ whenever $C' x^{a-1} > C x^{a 21/40}$ i.e. when $x$ is big enough and $a-1 > \frac{21}{40}a  \implies a > \frac{40}{19}$