# Prime number between $\sqrt{n}-n^{1/3}$ and $\sqrt{n}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Can anyone give me a proof or a reference for a proof that there exists a prime number between $\sqrt{n}-n^{1/3}$ and $\sqrt{n}$, for $n$ sufficiently large?

I am reading a lecture where the professor uses this fact but does not provide any reference.

Thank you!

Comment: Squaring twice, this is $[n^2-n^{\frac 43},n^2]$, which is slightly larger than one of the “conjectured intervals” which contain primes, $[n^2,(n+1)^2]$...

Comment: The prime counting function may be helpful for this problem.

Comment: Prime numbers are not square roots

Comment: @GKA I take it that you mean they are not irrational numbers. I mean, 5 is a prime number and it is the square root of 25.

Comment: Suggestion: Write $n=x^6$, so that the question is to show that $\pi(x^3)-\pi(x^3-x^2)\gt0$ for sufficiently large $x$.

Comment: I meant √5 is not a prime number,not the latter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some thoughts:

Put $n=t^4$. You are basically saying that the is a prime between $t^2-t^\frac43$ and $t^2$. For large enough values of $t$:

$$t^2-t^{\frac43}<t^2-2t<t^2-2t+1=(t-1)^2$$

So if there is always a prime between $(t-1)^2$ and $t^2$ (Legendre's conjecture), the statement in your book is definitely correct. But Legendre's conjecture has not been either proved or disproved yet.

On the other side, if you put $n=t^6$ you are basically saying that there is always a prime between $t^3-t^2$ and $t^3$. But:

$$t^3-t^2>t^3-3t^2+3t+1=(t-1)^3$$

It is proved that there is a [prime between two consecutive cubes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717838/primes-between-consecutive-cubes), like $(t-1)^3$ and $t^3$ for large enough values of $t$ ($t\ge e^{e^{33.217}}$) and the proof is fairly complex, not the easiest piece of math to read. But that fact is useless in this case. The statement in your book seems to be narrowing the gap even further because for large enough $t$:

$$(t-1)^3<t^3-t^2<t^3$$

Proving that there is a prime between $t^3$ and $t^3-t^2$ is even more difficult because the gap between numbers is now just 1/3 of the gap that we had before. It is also possible that such prime is not guaranteed to exist.

Answer (score 2):

I think this gets you in the ball park.

Number of primes  $<x\approx \frac{x}{ln(x)}$

$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{ln(\sqrt{x})}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\frac{x}{ln(x)}$

$\frac{x^{1/3}}{ln(x^{1/3})}=\frac{3}{x^{2/3}}\frac{x}{ln(x)}$

So it suffices to prove $(\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{3}{x^{2/3}})\frac{x}{ln(x)}>1$
for sufficient large x.

Perhaps the ratios could help mitigate relative error issues.

We want: $$\pi(\sqrt{x})-\pi(x^{\frac{1}{3}})>1$$
$$\frac{\pi(\sqrt{x})}{\pi(x^{\frac{1}{3}})}>1+\frac{1}{\pi(x^{\frac{1}{3}})}$$
$$\pi(\sqrt{x})>2\pi(x^{\frac{1}{3}})$$
Taking ratios of the approximations above,

$\frac{\pi(\sqrt{x})}{\pi(x^{\frac{1}{3}})}\approx \frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{1}{6}}$

$\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{1}{6}}\pi(x^{\frac{1}{3}})>\pi(x^{\frac{1}{3}})+1$

$\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{1}{6}}>1+\frac{1}{\pi(x^{\frac{1}{3}})}$

$\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{1}{6}}>2$

$x>729$

Comment: This is simply not true! The error of approximation is MUCH bigger than one for ALL values of x.

Comment: I tried this approach rigorously long ago (see Lemma 2 in my note "[On graphs without 4-cycles](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/mathmagic/1000/4cycles.ps)"). Namely, I used Rosser's bounds  $\frac n{\ln n+2}<\pi(n)<\frac n{\ln n-4}$ for $n\ge 55$ (Proc. London Math. Soc, 1939, v.45(2), p. 21-44). But they only yielded that  for every natural $n\ge 2$ there exists a prime number in $p\left\lfloor n-\frac {6n}{\ln n};n\right\rfloor$.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Barry Cipra and myself , putting $n=x^6$ gives the interval $[x^3, x^3-x^2]$.
Consider:
$$π(x^3) - π(x^3-x^2)$$
,where $π$ is the prime counting function.
As $n$ is large, $x$ is also large and for sufficiently large values of $x$ , $π$ can be approximated by the logarithmic integral $li (z) := \int^z_0 \frac {dt}{\ln t}$.
The series definition is:
$$li (e^z) := \gamma + \ln |z| + \sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac {z^n}{n.n!}$$
Now taking $e^u = x^3$ and $e^v = x^3 - x^2$, using the above mentioned definitions and approximations , and simplifying we have:
$$π(x^3) - π(x^3-x^2) ≈ \ln |\frac {u}{v}| + \sum \frac {u^n - v^n}{n.n!}$$
For large enough values of $u$ and $v$ the sum converges to values much larger than $1$. Hence,
$$π(x^3) - π(x^3-x^2) ≥1$$
As there is atleast one prime between $x^3$ and $x^3 - x^2$ our result is proved.

Comment: I disagree with your approach. You are basically replacing $\pi(x)$ with some other well-behaved function and then you are using that approximation to prove that $\pi(x)$ and $\pi(y)$ differ by more than **1**. $li(x)$ is a never an integer number so $\pi(x)$ and $li(x)$ are always different numbers and the difference could be anywhere in the (0,1) range. It also looks that you could prove Legendre's conjecture with this method easily.

Comment: Okay, I have used here an approximation that is quite accurate , but one is free to use the actual expansion for $π(z)$ (that's quoted on the corresponding wikipedia article) and come at the same result. Initially I too thought the same but that's too long to be posted.

Comment: What does it mean: *an accurate approximation*? Does it mean that for sufficiently big values of $x$ the difference between  $li(x)$ and $\pi(x)$ becomes arbitrarily small? No, their ratio becomes infinitely close to 1, but absolute values could be far apart. And that difference is not constant (sign and magnitude of that difference are constantly changing). You are talking about minimal **absolute** changes in $\pi(x)$ by discussing values of a related function that are probably miles apart.

Answer (score 2):

Even a stronger bound is proved by R. C. Baker, G. Harman, and J. Pintz in a paper “[The difference between consecutive primes II.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.360.3671&rep=rep1&type=pdf)”. For all $x > x_0$ the interval $[x-x^{0.525},x]$ contains prime numbers. With enough effort, the value of $x_0$ could be determined effectively.