# Prove there exist a prime $p$ between $n^3$ and $(n+1)^3-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading Elementary Number Theory by Underwood Dudley, in Section 22 "Formulas for Primes" he mentioned a theorem without providing proof:

there is an integer A such that if n > A, then there is a prime p such that
$$n^3<p<(n+1)^3-1$$

Is there a name for such theorem and how to prove it in an elementary way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Primes between consecutive cubes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717838/primes-between-consecutive-cubes)

Comment: Yes thank you! Glad to see it’s answered already

Comment: Welcome, it's my pleasure to help you.